# How to store the value of daterangepicker in variable and call the value in ajax on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date picker I am trying to **save value of my date picker in a variable** so that when I need to datepicker value like** call my Ajax it** will get the value from the saved value.

```
 $('#datepick').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'center',
    singleDatePicker: true
  },
  function(start) {
console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

}); 


<div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group-icon">
        <input class="input--style-4 js-datepicker" type="text" name="date" id="datepick">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-note input-icon js-btn-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey are you want the value of `date` by button click?

Comment: yes @KUMAR i want to save in variable

Comment: js variable & pass to ajax call??

Comment: Yes exactly so that I can use it anywhere or can save value in html and retrieve later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idButton").on('click', function() {
    var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val().split("-").reverse().join("/");
    console.log(fromDate);
      
       $.ajax({


           }); 
        
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fromDate" />


<input type="button" id="idButton" value="GetDate" />
```